# New column from multiple groups and conditions

Tags: r

I have a large dataframe, this is a simplified example:

```
df1<- data.frame(nest = c(1:12),
            plot = rep(c("a", "a", "a","b", "b", "b"), times = 2),
            year = rep(c(2015, 2016, 2017), times = 4),
            treatment = rep(c("Control", "Trap","Control","Trap","Control","Control"), times = 2))
```

Giving:

```
 nest plot year treatment
  1    a  2015   Control
  2    a  2016      Trap
  3    a  2017   Control
  4    b  2015      Trap
  5    b  2016   Control
  6    b  2017   Control
  7    a  2015   Control
  8    a  2016      Trap
  9    a  2017   Control
 10    b  2015      Trap
 11    b  2016   Control
 12    b  2017   Control
```

I'd like to create a new column, prevTrap, based on:

- grouped by plot, if treatment was Trap the previous year, prevTrap = 1, 
  otherwise 0
- Will always be zero if year = 2015

(for multiple nests in the same plot/year combinations)

Desired result:

```
 nest plot year treatment  prevTrap
  1    a  2015   Control       0
  2    a  2016      Trap       0
  3    a  2017   Control       1
  4    b  2015      Trap       0
  5    b  2016   Control       1
  6    b  2017   Control       0
  7    a  2015   Control       0
  8    a  2016      Trap       0
  9    a  2017   Control       1
 10    b  2015      Trap       0
 11    b  2016   Control       1
 12    b  2017   Control       0
```

I've tried different variations of the following code, which results in all prevTrap values = 0

```
df2<- df1 %>%
group_by(plot) %>%
mutate(prevTrap = ifelse(treatment == "Trap" &
                        year == year - 1, 
                        "1", "0"))
```

Should I treat year as a factor or numeric?

Comment: `year` cannot == `year - 1`. That's like saying 5 == 4. You probably need to use `lag(treatment)`, but that depends on whether year is ordered in your data frame by group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution that's not influenced by ordering of the dataframe:

```
#filter to get list of plots that were TRAP 2015 
Trap2015<-filter(df1, year == 2015 & treatment == "Trap")  
Trap2015plots<-droplevels(Trap2015$plot) 
Trap2015plots
```

The above obviously returns one level, "b", but for a larger dataset generates a list that can be input into the next portion of code. I did the same for year 2016 (not shown)

```
#create prevTrap column
df2<- df1 %>%
      mutate(prevTrap = ifelse(df1$plot %in% c("b") & #2015 plots = Trap
                         as.character(year) == "2016" |
                         df1$plot %in% c("a") & #2016 plots = Trap
                         as.character(year) == "2017",
                         "1", "0"))
```

Answer (score 0):

This works on your example data frame, but will only work on your larger dataset if it is structured in the same way, *i.e.* years are ordered within groups and groups are separated by other groups (abab...)

Also I named the data frame `df1` to avoid confusion with the `df()` function.

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>%
  group_by(plot) %>% 
  mutate(prevTrap = ifelse(lag(treatment) == "Trap", "1", "0")) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  replace_na(list("prevTrap" = 0))
```

Comment: Shoot. My real data set is not structured that way and I don't think it could be. Your answer is great for the question I asked, but I'll have to change my sample data frame to better reflect my real data set. Ideally I'd like a method that works regardless of order. Thank you